# Reading in decimal values with different endings

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I am reading through an rcv file and if I find the substring `602` in the line that starts with `T` then gather the data starting at an always defined starting point and going 27 more characters.  I want to read in any decimal value up to 10 points after just because.

When I go to pull the value and print `17.000` works, `17.030` works, `17.003` returns an empty string so the insert into SQL fails.  Why does the 3rd thing fail?  Is there something with .00X where X equals some single digit, not 0, or is there something else?

I have tried `String.Format`, pulling in as a decimal and converting, and just pulling in as a string and using that.

```
// This is currently what I am working with in C#.
String strWeight = "";

else if (strCode.Substring(0, 1) == "T" && strCode.Substring(13, 15).Contains("602"))
{
    //weight = Convert.ToDouble(strCode.Substring(19,27));
    //strWeight = weight.ToString();
    String.Format("{0:0.0000000000}", strWeight = strCode.Substring(19, 27));
```

This is currently what I have in rcv

```
 T000652706314602   17.003                            1R0C_MARA_NTGEW
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Returns: A string that is equivalent to the substring of length length that begins at startIndex in this instance, or Empty if startIndex is equal to the length of this instance and length is zero.

Comment: The body of the `if` must not be being executed, so therefore the `if` condition is not being met. Look to your `strCode` value.

Comment: The line `weight = Convert.ToDouble(strCode.Substring(19,27));` makes it work when I tried it. Could there be some invisible characters in your copy of the string with "17.003" which are changing its position? What you should do is look at the value of `strCode.Substring(19, 27)`.

Comment: Also, `if (strCode.StartsWith("T") && strCode.Substring(13, 15) == "602")` is more is line with saying what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generally recommend solving this kind of parsing tasks with regular expressions. Here is a working code example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var rcv =
                  "T000652706314602   17.000                            1R0C_MARA_NTGEW\n"
                + "T000652706314602   17.300                            1R0C_MARA_NTGEW\n"
                + "T000652706314602   17.030                            1R0C_MARA_NTGEW\n"
                + "T000652706314602   17.003                            1R0C_MARA_NTGEW";

            var rex = new Regex(@"^T\d{12}602\s+(\d+\.\d+)\s+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match match in rex.Matches(rcv)) {
                Console.WriteLine("found a match: " + match.Groups[1]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
found a match: 17.000
found a match: 17.300
found a match: 17.030
found a match: 17.003
```

Comment: This worked, so thank you for that, but unfortunately now I need a make a big change to one section.  Marked as answer.